# Asymptotics for this sum...

Tags: number-theory

$$\sum_{\substack{p \leq x \\ p=\left \lfloor n^{d} \right \rfloor}}\frac{1}{p}$$
with $0<d<1$; $d\in \mathbb{R}$; $n,p \in \mathbb{N}$

Can you give an asymptotics for this sum? Thank you.

Comment: can you show us what you have done? thank you

Comment: @James Are you familiar with the concepts? Thank you

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Is $n$ a real number ? IMO, your notation is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $d<1$, $n^d$ is more dense than $n$ and your sum is $H_{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ of which the asymptotics is well known.

Comment: I will accept the answer. p is a prime number. anyway

Comment: @resrser: I should have flipped the sheet...

Comment: Sorry for this...